# PC not starting - POST "Memory initialization error occurs" - RAM only working a one bank

Tags: memory, motherboard, reboot

**Setup:**

I have the following hardware

- CPU: Intel Core i5 3550 4x 3.30GHz So.1155
- MB (old): GA-Z77-DS3H MB
- MB (new): GA-Z77X-UD3H
- RAM: GB (2x 4096MB) Corsair Vengeance black
  DDR3-1600 DIMM CL9-9-9-24 Dual Kit
- Power: be quiet! Straight P. BQT
  E9 700W ATX23
- GraCa: SAPPHIRE Grafikkarte R9 290 TRI-X 4GB GDDR5

**Issues:**

*Issue 1:* The computer started for no reason during the day.

*Issue 2:* The computer did not start anymore. Pushing the power button, the PC powered up for few seconds and powers down. It starts again and ends up in a few seconds starting loop.

**Troubleshooting**

*For issue 1:* I checked windows event log, removed the power switch from the mb, checked wake settings (keyboard, lan) but didn't find the root cause. After a while issue 2 occurred.

*For issue 2:* I removed my graphics card, everything which was plugged in from the back, removed all SATA connectors, removed the RAM (some combinations), tested the power supply with a PSU tester. 
After removing nearly anything, the issues persisted. So it could only be the CPU (which I think is very unlikely), the board or the power supply (even if the 5$ PSU tester says its okay). I send the power supply to the vendor, due I had still warranty on it, but after test from the vendor, it is in a good condition.

So, it must be the board, right? **I bought a new board GA-Z77X-UD3H.** After putting everything back in a minimum setup together, the issue still persisted. :-(

This time i was able to check the POST code, where the board restarts. The last code before failing is 51, which is according to the manual **"Memory initialization error occurs"**.

I thought, memory? How? I tried on the old board different combinations of plugging one or both rams into the slots. This didn't made any difference.

So this time i did the following with the new board:

RAM1 or RAM2 to Slot 1 -> fails

RAM1 or RAM2 to Slot 2 -> fails

**RAM1 or RAM2 to Slot 3 -> works**

Windows is booting and working like a charm. I ran MemTest86 and the ram is absolutely fine. But it only works in Slot 3.

<strike>Slot 4 is currently unusable, because the after marked cpu cooler is blocking the slot. I could switch the orientation but I do not want to invest two more painful hours at the moment.</strike> (see update)

I checked the bios and the RAM settings are all set to auto. I also cleared the cmos and resetted all settings multiple times without any effect.

How comes that RAM2 is not working in Slot1/2? The board is completely new.

Any ideas what else could be the root cause? Any suggestions?

Thank you very much for your time reading this and trying to help!

Slot 1/2 not working on the new board? Not a board/ram/psu issue? CPU? But why is one slot working?

More clarification on Slot1-4 (from right to left):
Slot 1 DDR3_1

Slot 2 DDR3_3

Slot 3 DDR3_2

Slot 4 DDR3_4

[image: RAM Layout]

Intel® Processor Diagnostic Tool passes also without errors.

**UPDATE**

I spend the effort to switch the cpu cooler and used the opportunity to double check that all cpu pins are good. Now I have two RAM modules in slot 3 and 4 and both work. But only in single channel. I will run memtest again, just to be sure. Any idea why Slot1/2 do not work? What could it be? Bios is also up2date.

**UPDATE 2**

Memtest passed with two ram bars in slot3/4 worked.

Open questions:
- Is the old board broken?
- Why don't the RAM bars not work in slot1/2?

Comment: I would try to use new ram to make sure its not the ram. since you already got a new motherboard its very unlikely that its a bad board.